# "@fs" probelm in Vue3+ts+vite

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I put a logo in a vue page:

```
<el-col :span="4">
  <img src="../src/assets/img/logo.png" alt="sws-logo" class="sws-logo">
</el-col>
```

When I run the project, devtool shows:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/@fs/src/assets/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
Image(异步)
patchDOMProp @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:220
patchProp @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:313
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5209
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5499
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5014
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5499
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5014
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5499
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5014
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5499
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5014
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5284
mountElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191
processElement @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5156
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5028
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5708
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5040
render2 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6332
mount @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3824
app.mount @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1431
(匿名) @ main.ts:17
```

to give a broader picture, here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": "./src",
      "@c": "./src/components",
      "@store": "./src/stores",
      "@css": "./src/styles/css",
      "@a": "./src/assets",
      "@l": "./src/layouts",
    },
  },
});
```

**WHERE DOES THE @fs COME FROM??!**

Normally, when the project runs for the first time, it's all ok. But after a few time of F5, **@fs** pops out.

HELP plz!

in `<img src="../src/assets/img/logo.png" alt="sws-logo" class="sws-logo">`

I've tried @a/img/logo.png, @/assets/img/logo.png.

I ensure the path and file name is correct, case-sensitive correct.

Comment: why `../src/`?  The `..` implies your Vue page is not in the src folder.  Is that true? Can you show your file structure?  Otherwise try `<img src="src/assets/img/logo.png">`